# Java AppletViewer isn't initialized

Tags: java, java-8, applet, ubuntu-18.04

Applet not initialized

I have installed JDK8 on my ubuntu18.04 LTS machine. I have tried running code on other machine. It's working. I want to know how to configure applet viewer.

HelloWorld.java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

//Value passed through HTML

public class HelloWorld extends Applet{
    int x, y, w, h;

    public void init(){
         x = Integer.parseInt(getParameter (" xValue ")); //start x coordinate
         y = Integer.parseInt(getParameter (" yValue ")); // start y coordinate
         w = Integer.parseInt(getParameter (" wValue ")); // width
         h = Integer.parseInt(getParameter (" hValue ")); // height
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g ){
        g.drawRect (x, y, w, h ); // Graphics written method
    }
}
```

Hello.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <applet code = "HelloWorld.class" width = "300" height = "300" >
        <param name = xValue  value = 20 >
        <param name = yValue  value = 40 >
        <param name = wValue  value = 100 >
        <param name = hValue  value = 50 >
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should produce an applet running and draw a rectangle starting at given x y coordinate with given height and width.

Comment: why should it? applets are pretty much a dead thing.they can be nice to run in a browser, but since major browsers have been ending support for applets for quite a while now ..

Comment: Besides that you are riding a dead horse, you have to provide a meaningful problem description if you hope for help. Currently, all we know is that it “doesn’t work”.

Comment: <param /> instead of <param>. I fixed it myself. Thanks for your HELP!